# Substitute invalid UTF-8 characters in text file

Tags: regex, encoding, grep

I have a large text file that comes from a SQLite dump. Somehow some invalid characters got into the database and appear in the dump as �

Now I need to use some tool (grep, sed, tr) to remove (or replace) the � characters and keep all the rest (punctuation, accented characters etc).

My difficulty is finding how to represent non-printable characters in grep. The image bellow shows how I see the text in Atom

[image: file with bad characters opened in Atom]

And how gedit opens it:

[image: file with bad characters opened in gedit]

I placed an example file in the following link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vA6uogwGwGB14aJN3LT6Ju0LhadUMyEX

Any idea how to fix this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Could no do this using grep / sed / tr. So I ended up writing a simple Python script to ignore those characters.

The code is in:

https://gist.github.com/dvictori/c277aa12d0f7f1bcc5b0c061227f1442